# Can I access an ObjC constant by string name at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, constants, symbolic-references

I know that Objective-C allows me to refer to selectors by name using `@selector(@"name")` How can I access the following constant by name at runtime? In other words, I would pass `@"CONST_KEY"` somewhere and get `@"key"` back.

```
const NSString* CONST_KEY = @"key";
```

I think I can do this by first creating a key-value dictionary and then querying it at runtime, but I'm not sure if there's a better implementation.

To clarify with a specific use case:
I want to use a collection view cell reuse identifier `@"CONST_KEY"`, declared in my storyboard, and to be able to use this identifier to look up the value of `CONST_KEY` at runtime.

This way I hope to have a single place within my code to modify constants, rather than having to re-assign values in multiple classes. Having the two values linked will allow me to have a single action for all those cells using the `CONST_KEY` to define the action they are going to do.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - isn't this just a global variable? You access the global variable and get a value back? What does the extra layer of indirection get you? And if you need access via a key then a Dictionary seems to be the obvious way to go; what is wrong with a dictionary? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to link the global variable to a cell identifier in a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is just a C with added object functionality. So "CONST_KEY"  constant name is discarded during compilation. So you have to create your own class or use an NSDictionary to provide "constant_name"->"constant_value" functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call a selector to get the constant, you just need to expose it to your other classes. Also the constant should live inside of its relevant class. The method I use is the following.

in the header file right below your import statements (before @interface) declare this:

```
extern NSString *const CONST_KEY;
```

In the implementation file in the same place (above @interface and @implementation) declare this:

```
NSString *const CONST_KEY = @"key";
```

After you do that, in any class that imports the class where you declared your constant, you will be able to reference it simply with CONST_KEY

E.G.

```
[someDictionary objectForKey: CONST_KEY];
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", CONST_KEY);
```

etc etc – Using this convention is great for type safety. I use it all the time.

Comment: This misses the point of the question. The OP appears to want to access the constant at runtime using a dynamic reference at runtime, not a hardcoded reference (as shown in your answer).